# Excel日付データの入力と計算

Tags: python, pandas

現在、xlsxファイルに日付のデータを保存しています(dates.xlsx)。
date2-dateを求めたいと考えています。

```
date               date2
1973年3月     2018年8月
1984年10月        2018年5月
1990年1月     2017年12月
1954年          2016年1月
```

これを読み込むために、次のコードを書いています。

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df=pd.read_excel("dates.xlsx") 
print(df)
```

確認すると次のように出力されます。

```
"""
print(df)
                 date  date2
0  1973-03-01 00:00:00  43313
1                30956  43221
2                32874  43070
3                1954年  42370
"""
```

いろいろな形式で入力されてしまいます。

data2からdataを引き算する、"date2-date"を求めるために、次の手順を考えています。

1）形式を揃えるために、年のみで入力されているデータは、"年"を除く。
2) 日付データの入力形式を揃えて、引き算をする。

現在は、1)については、次のコマンドを行っているのですが、
年以外のデータはNaNになってしまいます。

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('年', '')
```

どなたか、手順2）まで求める方法を示唆して頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: とりあえず年のみのデータは置いておいて・・。
その他のデータ形式をそろえる為には、Excelでの操作で
データ全体に「セルの書式設定」→「日付（＊＊＊＊年＊＊月）」として
書式を統一したほうが良いかと思うのですが、
それ（元データを編集すること）は難しいのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。3百万件以上のデータがあるので、できれば手での操作は避けたいと考え、苦心しています。また、日付で設定しても、読み込むと、print(df)と書いたようになりました。

Comment: 別の方法として、CSV ファイルに変換し、エンコードをutf-8にして保存して、読み込んだところ、yyyy年mm月の形で、読み込むことができたので、string型のデータとして、作業することができました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡単に変換関数を書いてみました

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import re

def conv(d):
    if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime):
        # DateTime型のデータはそのまま
        return d
    if isinstance(d, int):
        # Int型のデータは 1900/1/1 からの日数を計算
        return datetime.datetime(1900,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=d)
    elif isinstance(d, str):
        # '****年'の形式の文字列をDateTime型に変換
        res = re.match('(\d+)年$', d)
        if res:
            return datetime.datetime(int(res.group(1)),1,1)
    print(d , "：このデータは変換できませんでした")
    return np.nan

df = pd.read_excel("dates.xlsx")
df = df.applymap(conv)
```

実際のデータで動作させてみないと全てのデータが変換できるかわかりませんが、とりあえず

- Datetime型：そのまま
- Int型：1900年１月１日からの日数としてDatetime型に変換
- 文字列："XXXX年" の形式を Datetime型に変換
- 上記以外 : NaN を返す

という実装となっておりますので、applymap() などを使って全てのデータに適用させてみると良いかと思います。

変換後は

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

を行って、"date"と"date2"列がDatetime型となっていることを確認ください

Comment: 具体的なコードを示していただき、ありがとうございます。実行させていただきます。